# Unable to select private repos in my github organization in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to connect my **data factory** resource using my **Organization Name** in **Github**, but the private repos inside my oraganization does not show up in the dropdown.

Any one knows how to enable it?

I search for any configuration in github to enable it, but looks like everything is ok.

Comment: Are you choosing DevOps or Github?

Comment: Looks like it works, but only with GitHub pro account.